# Jupyter notebook and visual studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, ipynb

After I create my environment using conda and installed the modules, libraries, when I open in browser

```
D:\Computer Vision\Proiect Cava>conda activate TestEnv

(TestEnv) D:\Computer Vision\Proiect Cava>jupyter notebook
```

the code works fine but if I run the ipynb it in visual studio code it gives me errors regarding the existence of imported libraries.

```
d:\Computer Vision\Proiect Cava\Laborator 6.ipynb Cell 4 line 1
----> 1 img = cv.imread('data/train/01.jpg')
      2 result=extrage_careu(img)
      3 show_image('img',result)

NameError: name 'cv' is not defined
```

How can I solve this because i set the kernel/ interpreter correctly?

I tried everything like importing the path to the library directory, recreating the environment and reinstall libraries.

Comment: Is this the same issue as your other question?